# Mac OSX exclude xdebug for cli

Tags: php, macos, command-line-interface, xdebug

I would like to prevent xdebug from loading when using php from the command line. I'm using Mac OSX version 10.10.5

I am aware of how to accomplish this when extensions are loaded directly within `php-cli.ini`, however my set up loads all extensions from a `conf.d` directory

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/etc/php/5.6
total 392
drwxr-xr-x   8 hpenny  admin    272 27 Jan 10:02 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 hpenny  admin    136 21 Jul  2015 ..
drwxr-xr-x  10 hpenny  admin    340 27 Jan 09:54 conf.d
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin   1558 21 Jul  2015 pear.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin  72658 27 Jan 09:59 php-cli.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin  22885 21 Jul  2015 php-fpm.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin  22868 21 Jul  2015 php-fpm.conf.default
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin  72658 16 Nov 10:21 php.ini
$ ls -la /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  10 hpenny  admin   340 27 Jan 09:54 .
drwxr-xr-x   8 hpenny  admin   272 27 Jan 10:02 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin   149 21 Jul  2015 ext-apcu.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin   300 21 Jul  2015 ext-igbinary.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin    62 21 Jul  2015 ext-imagick.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin    59 21 Jul  2015 ext-mcrypt.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin    65 21 Jul  2015 ext-memcache.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin  4122 21 Jul  2015 ext-memcached.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin    53  7 Aug 15:00 ext-tidy.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 hpenny  admin    64 21 Jul  2015 ext-xdebug.ini
```

Is there any way to exclude ext-xdebug.ini being loaded for php-cli.ini only?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **not**. There's no extension list exclusion in php.

You can only **disable xdebug globally** and then load it when needed using eg an alias. Here is an example for **composer** from the [official docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#xdebug-impact-on-composer).

```
# Load xdebug Zend extension with php command
alias php='php -dzend_extension=xdebug.so'

# PHPUnit needs xdebug for coverage.
# In this case, just make an alias with php command prefix.
alias phpunit='php $(which phpunit)'
```